# Texture Bake contains aditional noise?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

Spent ages making this texture seamless only to have square patches of extra noise show up when Baking, not sure what I did wrong.
Partial FIX: Increasing the Dimension value to 0.7 (or above) in the "Seamless Musgrave" node.
[image]

[image]

Additional problem - I now seem to have a 1 pixel line of noise running along what I imagine to be the seam from the Seperate XYZ node in the "Seamless Musgrave" node. Adjusting the Scale Value to 125.6 seems to shrink it down to be almost non-visible but is still a problem I would like to solve.
[image]

Comment: I don't know enough about shader nodes to explain the reason for the extra noise but it seems that you can get rid of it by increasing the Dimension value to 0.7 (or above) in the "Seamless Musgrave" node. This results in some loss of definition in the texture, some of which you can get back by decreasing the position of the white slider in the following Color Ramp. (For example from 0.545 to 0.410).